# Incompressible, inviscid flow through a square

Tags: aerodynamics, cfd

I am currently writing CFD with relaxation technique for inviscid and incompressible flow, and I tested it on square, here is result:

[image]

Where direction of the flow from left to right, cold colors->low velocity, hot colors->high velocity. I doubt due to d'Alembert's paradox because in such case pressure on both sides won't be equal.

Comment: Please state clearly the question you wish to be answered. Without a clearly stated question, this thread may well be closed.

Comment: "Through" a square?